# Eclipse plugin development: Missing dependencies at runtime

Tags: eclipse, noclassdeffounderror

### Background

I'm currently trying to extend Junit (org.eclipse.jdt) in order to do some tracing.
Therefore I created my own plugin project which (among others) provides a class which should be used by the junit runtime plugin.

I have setup my project as a dependency for junit and the package containing my class is listed as "exported" in my Manifest in the runtime tab. If I run the plugins as an eclipse application everything builds and starts allright and.

### Problem

However, if in the started eclipse I perform a "Run as Junit", I get a NoClassDefFoundError concerning my class. In my understanding this means, that at runtime my class is not visible in the started eclipse. I thus printed the classpath while running and like expected my plugin doesn't show up.

Do I have to add my plugin to the "runtime" settings of the junit plugin? In the Manifest, my package is not available under the "export -> add" button. I tried importing a jar of my plugin and configuring those exports manually here, but this did not help either.

My thought process kind of gets stuck with this "run in run" configuration...
Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Digging deeper in the code I found that the reason for the error is, that the part which calls my code and throws the error is run in a seperately started VM which has its classpath set via code. Nothing was wrong with the configuration, it just was not used in this case.

So if you ever stumble upon a "VMRunnerConfiguration" while having classpath problems, this might be your problem. ;)